# Buddypress JSON API Plugin to show particular User activity

Tags: wordpress, buddypress, wordpress-json-api

Im using Buddypress JSON Api plugin, wanted to know how single User Activity can be displayed.

The function which is provided by BP JSON API is activity_get_activities() which display all user's activity through out the website.But i wanted to display only for single user.

For Example: http://websiteurl/api/buddypressread/activity_get_activities/?userid=1

In the above example, if i pass userid=1 then all the activity by the user 1 will be displayed not by all other user's